# Check typeof text data

Tags: javascript

I have a string like in this link http://pastie.org/private/n7bu5qlknphtyyv5sqla.

I am trying to decode it using different methods

```
new Uint8Array(encodedString);
```

and also tried some octal decoders online but no success. Can anyone help me to understand encoding type and how to decode it.

**Edit**:

Progress: It is a file loaded from client side. Before I was using `readAsBinaryString` and now I changed it to `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);` Now I am getting `ArrayBuffer` and converted it to `new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)`. It seems now I have some data zipped data.

Comment: Where did the string come from originally?

Comment: @GregPrisament Updated my question. Please have a look at it